# skip the ansible role and move to next one if that server joined to AD already otherwise execute current role

Tags: ansible

If my ansible task reports the server join the domain already,it should move to next role and if not it should move with the domain join role.

```
root@ghepoc:/home/hasabd# wbinfo -t
checking the trust secret for domain TESTDEV via RPC calls succeeded
```

If the above command shows succeeded then should move to next role otherwise execute the current role.

```
---
- name: "Check domain status"
  command: "wbinfo -t"
  register: "domain"
  ignore_errors: True

- name: AD join status
  debug:
    msg: "{{ domain.stdout }}"
  when: "domain.rc == 0"

- name: Include OS-specific variables.
  include_vars: "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"

- include: setup-RedHat.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat'

- include: setup-Debian.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'

- include: config-RedHat.yml
  when:
    - ad_create_config | bool
    - ansible_os_family == 'RedHat'

- include: config-Debian.yml
  when:
    - ad_create_config | bool
    - ansible_os_family == 'Debian'
```

I can see "failed_when" option. Is there anyway we can mention, if we domain.rc = o skip this role or otherwise

Comment: What did you try so far? From what I understand, you could simply launch a task that execute the command, register the result in a variable, then condition the call to the role with a `when` checking the `rc` or the presence of some words in the `stdout`.

Comment: So you want to skip all the tasks after the first one if `domain.rc != 0`, right? Simply create a `block` containing them and conditioned by a `when: domain.rc != 0`